# How to tell whether a Javascript error is 'blocking'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there such a thing as blocking vs non blocking Javascript errors?

What I mean is that I've seen my site report some errors, but the process involved still completes successfully (as far as I can tell). These errors include:
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.nodeName.toLowerCase')
TypeError: e.nodeName is undefined
(these are always from my general JQuery library file)

These are what I mean by 'non-blocking' errors, since the scripts involved seem to complete successfully.

If there is such a thing as blocking v non-blocking, what is the correct terminology for it, and how can I tell the difference between the 2 (eg so that I can prioritise investigating blocking errors)?

Thanks

Comment: catched vs. uncaught

Comment: All JavaScript errors are fatal, but they can be [`try..catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)ed. But if visible effects happen before the error line, they still take effect - it doesn't roll back anything when an error happens. This can result in things appearing to work, at least partially.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever

```
throw Error;
```

The exception bubles up the function stack. If it reaches the end of it, it throws an *uncaught* (=unexpected) exception. This halts the complete program as its unlikely to work properly anymore.

However it can be *catched*  (=expected exception):

```
try{
 someerrorproducingfunc();
 //continue after success
}catch(e){
 //continue after error
 console.error(e);
}
//continue after error+success
```

So the code proceeds ( leaving out the *continue after sucess* part). However, if you use *console.error* it logs sth that looks like an error.

ressource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw

---

Note that *Error* is just an object constructor in js:

```
new Error("test");
```

While *throw* throws an *exception*...

Answer (score 0):

No. All un-caught error are blocking, they will end the execution of the entire call stack. However, an error that happens after various operation will not revert back to a situation like before. Making an AJAX call, and then having an undefined error will not cancel the call for example. Demo:

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    let a  = 5;
    
    console.log(a); // 5
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(a); // 10
        // will execute because it is a fresh stack
        // the variable a is 10 despite and not 12 because it happened after
    }, 250);
    
    const withError2 = function () {
        a = 10;
        a.x.z = 2; // Error
        a = 12; // never executes because it comes after the error
    }
    
    withError2();
    console.log(a); // never executes because it comes after the error
}());
```